# Specifying Colors Per Page

Tags: color

Using the `leaflet` package, I am trying to create a flyer for a document. I have specified the background color `NavyBlue` for pages `1`, `2`, `4`, and `5`. Unfortunately, the default text color, black, is difficult to read on that background. To fix that, I would like to use the color, white. However, I must only use that color on pages `1`, `2`, `4`, and `5`. It would not show up on the other, white pages. How can I accomplish this in LaTeX?

Below is a sample file:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{leaflet}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Sample Document}
\author{Anonymous}
\date{\today}

\AddToBackground{1}{
  \put(0,0){\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}}
\AddToBackground{2}{
  \put(0,0){\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}}
\AddToBackground{4}{
  \put(0,0){\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}}
\AddToBackground{5}{
  \put(0,0){\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

`tcolorbox` package can apply different options to each fragment from a broken box. Then it's possible to include all text from the leaflet inside a `breakable, blankest` tcolorbox (`blankest` doesn't change paragraph format) and as every fragment is identified with a particular number, we can use it to fix the color of the text.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{leaflet}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\title{Sample Document}
\author{Anonymous}
\date{\today}

\AddToBackground{1}{
  \put(0,0){\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}}
\AddToBackground{2}{
  \put(0,0){\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}}
\AddToBackground{4}{
  \put(0,0){\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}}
\AddToBackground{5}{
  \put(0,0){\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}}

\begin{document}

% White color for `title` is forced.
{\color{white}\maketitle}

% A breakable blankest colorbox with an `extras` option which is evaluated  
% on each fragment identified by a `\thetcolorboxnumber` 
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, blankest, 
      code={\newcommand{\mytextcolor}{%
          \ifnum\thetcolorboxnumber=3 black%
          \else\ifnum\thetcolorboxnumber=6 black%
          \else white\fi\fi}},
      extras = {colupper=\mytextcolor}
]
\Blinddocument
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very clever solution! :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Nice to hear it! By the way, is this the correct way of using `code` and `extras`?

Comment: Yes, I think so.